# Using rubberBand to select QGraphicItems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I am trying to use to `rubberBand` to select some `QGraphicItems` that are associated with some predetermined X and Y coordinates. The user is able to zoom with the mouse wheel and pan with the center mouse button. The user can click the left mouse button and draw a selection window, but I am not currently able to select any of the points. I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840289/how-to-use-qrubberband-with-qrect-class-in-pyqt) that I am trying to adapt to mine, but right now it is not finding my Custom `Point` object.

I'm assuming I'm going wrong with `self.findChildren(QGraphicsItem)` and because I am using my own custom `QGraphicsItem` it is not able to find the ones that have been added. I have tried to use the `findChildren` function with `Point` Object, but have come back with the same results. Any advice and help are greatly appreciated.

**Current Code**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt

class LogObject(QObject):
    hovered = pyqtSignal()
    notHovered = pyqtSignal()

class Point(QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, x, y,name):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.name = name
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.log = LogObject()

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemSelectedChange:
            if value:
                self._brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
            else:
                self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor("red"))
        self.log.hovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        self.log.notHovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.name)
        QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fitInView) # This is done so that it can fit into view on load
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y,'Point__'+str(i))
                p.log.hovered.connect(self.hoverChange)
                p.log.notHovered.connect(self.notHoverChange)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0


    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def hoverChange(self):
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def notHoverChange(self):
        self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
                self.rubberBand.hide()
                selected = []
                rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
                for child in self.findChildren(QGraphicsItem):
                    if rect.intersects(child.geometry()):
                        selected.append(child)
                print ('Selection Contains:\n '),
                if selected:
                    print ('  '.join(
                        'Item: %s\n' % child.name for child in selected))
                else:
                    print (' Nothing\n')
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Fit Into View')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.fitPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        self.viewer.fitInView()

    def fitPoints(self):
        self.viewer.fitInView()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The findChildren method finds the QObject children of the Viewer, but the QGraphicsItems are not QObject and are not children of the Viewer, so it is not the correct solution.

The procedure is to convert the rectangle of the QRubberBand that is in coordinates of the viewport of the Viewer to the scene using the method mapToScene, then use the method items() passing the rectangle in coordinates of the scene.

```py
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.changeRubberBand = False
        if self.rubberBand.isVisible():
            self.rubberBand.hide()
            rect = self.rubberBand.geometry()
            rect_scene = self.mapToScene(rect).boundingRect()
            selected = self.scene().items(rect_scene)
            if selected:
                print(
                    "".join("Item: %s\n" % child.name for child in selected)
                )
            else:
                print(" Nothing\n")
        QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
    # ...
```

On the other hand I see that you are creating Point based on QGraphicsItem, the simplest thing is that it inherits from QGraphicsRectItem:

```py
class Point(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        super(Point, self).__init__(QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.name = name
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.log = LogObject()
        self.setPos(x, y)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemSelectedChange:
            self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green) if value else QBrush(Qt.black))
        return QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor("red"))
        self.log.hovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setBrush(QColor("black"))
        self.log.notHovered.emit()
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(self.name)
        QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)

# ...
class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    # ...
    def setItems(self):
        # ...
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(self.data["x"], self.data["y"])):
            p = Point(x, y, "Point__" + str(i))
            p.log.hovered.connect(self.hoverChange)
            p.log.notHovered.connect(self.notHoverChange)
            self._scene.addItem(p)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
# ...
```

Comment: This defiantly answers my question about how to select the points, but I do have multiple points with the same X and Y's. This does not seem to be printing them out in the selection window, is that because of how I am loading them into the window or does that have something else to do with how it is selecting the points?

Comment: @laxer The complete code of my test is in the following link: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/f305119027ae3b85dfcf8a3ef8c00238

Comment: You know what, you are 100% right, My coordinate system is off from what I was thinking. And the dots are actually mirrored from what I wanted. So it is picking up both. I was only testing the positions I thought should have doubles so that is my fault. Thank you again for all your help and explanations. I have learned a lot.